# Android: Facebook Invalid Key hash

Tags: android

I integrated Facebook in my app,I can set release key hash but it is working only in one device.After installing it to another device it logs in for the first time and second time onwards it shows the error

> Invalid key-doesn't match key hash. (Please refer the image below for description)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BypD.png)
Please guide.

I tried but haven't got it fixed.
I tried below code,but not work,I can get same release hash key for 2 apps

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.test.sample",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        System.out.println("******"+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));   
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: The easiest way will be replacing the one you set in developers facebook with the one given in your error msg..